# How can I get the checkbox group's Label Value?

Tags: java, lotus-notes, xpages

In Xpage's CheckboxGroup, I have to get the values of both value and Label.

I am using getComponent("ID").getValue() for getting the value... { I acn get the values]

For Label,

getcomponent("id").getAttributes().get("xxx")

getcomponent("id").getAttributes().values()

The second one{label finding], Which is not working...

Expecting better Idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In client side Javascript,

```js
var oCheck= document.forms[0].elements["#{id:Column}"]
var label=null;
var value1=null;
for(var i=0;i<oCheck.length;i++)
{

if(document.forms[0].elements["#{id:Column}"][i].checked)
{

    label=label+","+((document.forms[0].elements["#{id:Column}"][i].parentNode.textContent))
    value1=value1+","+(document.forms[0].elements["#{id:Column}"][i].value)
}
}

document.getElementById("#{id:first}").value=value1;
document.getElementById("#{id:second}").value=label;
```

Comment: This will work on CSJS., for getting Label value and actual value of our check box group...

Answer (score 1):

You could try following:

```
try {
    return getLabelFor(getComponent("inputText1")).getValue()
} catch(e) {
    return "No label"
}
```

See http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc%2Fr_wpdr_globals_getlabelfor_r.html for dccumentation.

**Update** in your case you might need to iterate through childrens of CheckBoxGroup:

```
var t1 = getComponent("cbg1").getChildren();
var l1 = t1.get(1);

return l1.getItemLabel();
```

This works for manually entered values. Didn't check if result will be the same if Values is computed or comes from Data Binding.

Comment: yup... It is also not fetching the Label value of my chackBoxGroup... It always goes to catch

Comment: getComponent("id").getSelectedValues()- It is working fine. Thank you very much for your expensive(Valuable) time.

Comment: So, you wanted to get the label of checkbox selected by user in a checkbox group, am I right?

Comment: Yes @Egor Margineanu: In Client side I am getting., But in Server side I am not able to get via getParent() method